# webdriver-manager update command always fails first time but passes after

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriver-manager

When I execute `webdriver-manager update` for the first time I always see the following error

```
PS H:\> webdriver-manager update
webdriver-manager: using global installed version 12.1.2
[09:55:15] I/config_source - curl -oC:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\standalone-response.xml https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/
[09:55:15] I/config_source - curl -oC:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
[09:55:15] I/config_source - curl -oC:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\gecko-response.json https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:622:25)
```

However, whenever I run it again it always executes successfully. I have experienced this only in my current company and I know it also occurs for other colleagues so I assume it must somehow be the proxy but cannot understand how it passes successfully afterwards.

Any solutions or recommendations of how to better troubleshoot from my end would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I'm using powershell to execute the commands

Comment: what is nodejs version?

Comment: @Dev Node version is `v8.12.0`, I believe the selenium server version is I am using is `3.141.59`

Comment: The current version is 12.1.5. Please update your webdriver-manager version.

Comment: you can always try installing the latest version usingnpm i webdriver-manager@latest --save

Comment: This is currently happening to me. Were you able to solve this? @DublinDev

Comment: @RichardJimenez Unfortunately I don't recall ever finding a solution. I seem to remember the cause was due to the webdriver folders where the drivers where stored was not existing and needed to be created. It passes on subsequent runs because the folders are created after the first failed attempt

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on and off in previous versions of webdriver-manager. The only thing that fixed it, was upgrading to the latest version. We are also behind a proxy, so that might be the problem. 
Maybe repost this under https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues so it gets picked up by the developers?